# d3 barchart animates on load, but not on update

Tags: d3.js

I have a bar chart drawing correctly when the page loads:

```
valueBar = chart.append("rect")
    .attr({ "y": height, "height": 0, "width": valueWidth, "class": "standard" })
    .transition()
    .duration(500)
    .attr("class", chartColor(items.count))
    .attr("height", function () { return (items.count / items.max * height) + (valueBorder * 2) + (border * 2) })
    .attr("y", function () { return (height - (items.count * height / items.max)) - valueBorder });
```

When I am trying to update the bar I get a weird error:

*Cannot read property '1' of undefined*

Here is my update code:

```
$rootScope.$watch('billHandler2', function (d) {
    if (d3Instance) {
        items = d;
        valueBar.transition()
            .attr("class", chartColor(items.count))
            .attr("height", function () { return (items.count / items.max * height) + (valueBorder * 2) + (border * 2) })
            .attr("y", function () { return (height - (items.count * height / items.max)) - valueBorder });
    }
});
```

The update works when I remove the `.transition() and .duration(500)` when the bar gets initially drawn.  The update will animate as I want, but the bar does not animate on page load.

Can someone with more D3 knowledge let me know why I might be getting this error when the initial bar animates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When chaining methods be careful of what's being returned to the variable.  In your case `.transition` returns a transition object, when you meant to save the `rect` selection to valueBar.

```
valueBar = chart.append("rect")
  .attr({ "y": height, "height": 0, "width": valueWidth, "class": "standard" });

valueBar
  .transition()
  .duration(500)
  .attr("class", chartColor(items.count))
  .attr("height", function () { return (items.count / items.max * height) + (valueBorder * 2) + (border * 2) })
  .attr("y", function () { return (height - (items.count * height / items.max)) - valueBorder });
```